# python: difference between \x and \u in characters

Tags: python, unicode, hex

I trying to understand unicode and byte representation using hex. So in python i tried the below.

```
> 'I am a string Ņ'.encode('utf-8')
> b'I am a string \xc5\x85'
```

Here i see `\xc5\x85` whats the meaning of this representation. The actul unicode for `Ņ` is `\u0145`

How `\u0145 = \xc5\x85`

Comment: the bytes `C5 85` is the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode Codepoint `U+0145`. They are not equal, as one is an encoding of the unicode codepoint, the other is the unicode codepoint itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 - Encode/Decode vs Bytes/Str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472650/python-3-encode-decode-vs-bytes-str)

Comment: instead of `b'I am a string \xc5\x85'` it should show as `b'I am a string \u0145'`

Comment: I am not sure, i have to go through it.

Comment: No, in Python 3, the leading `b` prefix for a string literal turns that string into a `bytes` object, which is not a `str`.  You cannot put unicode codepoints (which may be written as `\uXXXX`, X being a hexadecimal digit) inside a `bytes` literal.

Comment: But we can put characters like `I am a string`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116818/ascii-code-point-vs-character-encoding - Looks nearer to my question. My question is related to code point vs encoding.

Comment: Python lets programmers write `b"I am a string"` simply because every single character enclosed by the double-quote has a standard encoding via the ASCII codec, from which it maps directly to bytes. In actuality you should be reading that construct as `b"\x49\x20\x61\x6d\x20\x61\x20\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67"`.

Comment: `'I am a string Ņ'.encode('unicode_escape')` shows `b'I am a string \\u0145'`

Comment: So its an internal mapping between code points and encoding. I thought that the mapping will be same as the codepoint.

Comment: The `'\\'` in `b'I am a string \\u0145'` forms a literal backslash character ` \ ` as that is the complete escape sequence, so what you are in fact getting is the encoded form of what `repr` might generate for the original `str`.  As I noted before you need to understand that `str` is note `bytes`, and your assumptions of this naive conversion is incorrect.

Comment: To be absolutely pedantic, you have to look at each individual character separately.  One way to do so is to encode the output as a `str` and then cast to `list` (i.e. `[chr(i) for i in b'I am a string \\u0145']`), you will then see this: `['I', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'a', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', '\\', 'u', '0', '1', '4', '5']` - note how the `Ņ` character is not actually present inside that output, only the 6 byte long `\u` prefixed encoding.

Comment: [This would be a much more basic SO question on this topic that is programming language agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331819/whats-the-difference-between-a-character-a-code-point-a-glyph-and-a-grapheme)